# Como alterar a classe de um botão de acordo com seu id e o valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3

Pretendo modificar a classe de um botão de acordo com seu id e seu valor. Cada `<button>` tem identificadores iguais, porém valores diferentes.

Tentei desta forma abaixo, no entanto somente o primeiro botão é modificado, independente do valor que é inserido para a variável `value`. Para este caso abaixo deveria modificar a classe referente ao botão com texto **MARCELEZA**.

```js
var value = 4;
$("#month").val(value).attr('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-xs');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="margin: 20px">
  <button id="month" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="1">BALACO BACCO</button>
  <button id="month" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="2">CAPTÃO G.NASCIMENTO</button>
  <button id="month" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="3">JBUENO'S DIA</button>
  <button id="month" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="4">MARCELEZA</button>
</div>
```

Como posso alterar a classe de um botão de acordo com seu id e o valor?

Comment: Nunca repita o atributo ID em HTML.

Comment: Obs: `.val()` não é para pegar os elementos é para setar valores neles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar seletor `[value=X]`:

```js
var value = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1); // << Para explicar gera um número qualquer, clique em "Executar" para selecionar um diferente.

$("#month button[value='" + value + "']").attr('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-xs');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="month" style="margin: 20px">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="1">BALACO BACCO</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="2">CAPTÃO G.NASCIMENTO</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="3">JBUENO'S DIA</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" value="4">MARCELEZA</button>
</div>
```

> Por conveniência, para evitar repetições de `id`, utilizei o `id` diretamente na `div`, dessa forma é possível buscar por `button` que possui o valor dentro da `div` com tal `id`.

---

```
#month button[value='3']
```

Essa query, *se assim pode ser chamada*, irá encontrar qualquer elemento com o `id` igual à `month` e então encontra o `button`, filho do `month`, que o `value` que seja igual a `3`.

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou :/

Comment: De qualquer forma, fiz alterações para remover a repetição de `id` também. ;)

Comment: Inkelizmente você respondeu bem e de primeira, já tem o upvote garantido, acho que é isso mesmo que o AP procura.

Comment: Valeu, funcionou beleza!